# Permissions Issue: Get info such as albums and photos of a FRIEND of a user whom installed my FB app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

How do I get info such as albums and photos of a FRIEND of a user whom installed my FB app?
The issue is a permissions issue because I can get the information about the user which installed my app? which by the way, gave permissions to permanent access token and I have it kept in my DB.

Here's the scenario: a user installed my FB app and is using my app and is suppose to see photos of a FRIEND of another user that installed my app.
When users install my app, it requires "offline_access" just for that purpose so the application can get data such as photos of the user's friend.

here's the code I'm using to get the profile photos of a user:

```
FB.api('/' + userID + '/albums', function (response) {
            for (album in response.data) {

                // Find the Profile Picture album
                if (response.data[album].name == "Profile Pictures") {

                    // Get a list of all photos in that album.
                    FB.api(response.data[album].id + "/photos", function (response) {

                        //The image link
                        var arrayOfPhotos = '';
                        var numberOfPhotos = 0;
                        var image_url = new Array();
                        for (photo in response.data) {
                            //here I have some code to show the photos...
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

this code works really well when the userID is of a user that installed the app but doesn't work on users that didn't. Obviously, the user that installed the app has access to their friends photo... so how do I perform this task in behalf of a user which installed my app but not the one that is logged in..

thanks. I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do violates FB Policy:

See https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#policies

> II. 4. A user's friends' data can only be used in the context of the
>   user's experience on your application.

So your app that tries to show User A photos of a friend of User B can't work.

Comment: That's not really what that policy refers to, although you are correct that there's no API to return a friends' photos